# How do I maintain alignment in Ms-Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, file-transfer, copy-paste, microsoft-word-2013, alignment

Question: Is there any way to maintain the intact aligment of the words wriitten in a "Ms-Word file"(when copied to other computers) without converting them into pdf ?

My problem: In exams, we are to write our projects in Ms-Word, copy the documents in a pendrive and print it out from a printer attached to another Computer.

So recently I have been doing so and it so happened that when I was to copy the Word File to the other computer and print it out, I found the whole "alignment" of the Word File was jumbled up in the new computer, resulting in utter harrasment.

But we are not allowed to convert the Word file into "Pdf" format..

So is there any way to handle this problem without converting them into pdf ?

Comment: Start by using fonts available on the other computer. Times New Roman and Arial are usually safe choices.

Comment: Thank you..Should remember this from next time..